# Get people and group column in Sharepoint by using of REST API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to bring information from a column type person and group, from a Sharepoint´s list. I will use get with with REST API.

I would appreciate any advice and help on this.

Thanks a lot in advance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that using the something like:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('customlistname')/items?$select=Users/EMail,Users/FirstName,Users/LastName,Users/EMail&$expand=Users/Id
```

Please see here for more info:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31210.sharepoint-2013-get-user-details-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api.aspx

Comment: Thank a lot for you advice